# jQuery Ajax Hide Div ID in index page based on Ajax function

Tags: php, jquery

**index.php**

```
$('.report_posts').live("click",function() 
{
     $.ajax(
     type: "GET",
     url: "mini_report_post.php",
     data: 'post_id=' + ID,
     success: function (data)
     });
});

<div id="stbody<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
</div>
```

**mini_report_post.php**

```
$(".btn_report").click(function() 
    {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");

        var uid_modal = $("#uid_modal").val();
        var my_uid = $("#my_uid").val();
        var dataString = 'uid_modal='+ uid_modal +'&my_uid='+ my_uid;
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "update_block_user.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#stbody"+ID).fadeOut();
                    $('.modal').modal('hide');
                }
            });

        return false;
    });
<button id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="btn_report"/>
```

I want to hide `$("#stbody"+ID).fadeOut();` after Success Ajax function, but it didn't work. The stbody won't fade out.
I tried above code, but still can't
Any idea?

Comment: just check by putting alert inside success callback and check if success callback is hitting or not...and instead of `.live()` use `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated since jquery 1.7.1

Comment: I tried alert, and the value is "object object"

Answer (score 0):

try this change the code in `mini_report_post.php`

your code :: `$(".btn_report").click(function()`

replace with this :: `jQuery(document).on('click','.btn_report', function(){`